# How put result of Sql-query to SpreadSdheet by Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc

I have Google Cloud Sql database. I want get max date from column by SQL-query to same cell of Google Spreadsheet.
I wrote  next function:

```
function readFromTable() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Pivot Table');
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM 1line)');
  var cell = sheet.getRange('B1'); 
  cell.setValue(results);
}
```

But I got "*JdbcResultSet*" in 'B1'.
What I'm doing wrong?

Result of SQL query is:

```
+---------------------+
| MAX(datetime)       |
+---------------------+
| 2020-08-14 15:21:13 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: What is the type of `results`? How will you get a array from jdbcResultset ? Search documentation. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: If datetime is actually a number then you should be able to just use `SELECT MAX(datetime) from 1line` assuming that 1line is a table name.  If datetime is actually a datetime object then my guess is that MAX(datetime) won't work and you will have to get all of them returned to the spreadsheet as a column and convert them to `Date().valueOf()` or `Date().getTime()` and then find the maximum.  In your current situation I suspect that you are not getting a 2d array at all but I could be wrong.

Comment: I know that problem in type of ```results```. I try to use methods of jdbcResultset but nothing works. Ok. I'll try Date().valueOf(). Thanks

Comment: A `Statement.executeQuery` returns a `java.sql.ResultSet`, you need to iterate over that result set and retrieve values from it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#read_from_the_database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone!
I get it!

```
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Pivot Table');
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM 1line');
  while (rs.next()) {
      var x = rs.getString("MAX(datetime)");
      var cell = sheet.getRange("B1"); 
      cell.setValue(x);
  }
```

It's work!